# Fetching path specific cookie on pushState

Tags: javascript, cookies, pushstate

I guess this is possible, but is there any way of fetching pathspecific cookies (ones set with path=/XXX), when navigating as a onepageapp with window.history.pushState, to that new path?

Comment: depends on who set the cookie/wether this specific cookie can be read by JS.

Comment: The cookies are set with JavaScript and can be read by JavaScript. But the navigation is done with window.history.pushState("", "xxx", "/XXX");. I don't think there is any possible way of reading the cookie specific for the path XXX when navigating to the url /XXX from /, only using the pushState code. But I hope I'm wrong

Comment: nice one. Didn't know that the cookie variable doesn't get updated when playing with `pushState()`. After all, the `location` properly represents the new url. You can still hack that by actually loading the page in an (invisible/hidden) iframe, at least long enough that the 'contentDocument' is built and provides you access to the cookies. But as said, this is only a dirty hack. You're setting these cookies in the frontend, why do you need to recover their content? What kind of data do they contain? Maybe the localStorage is a better place to store that data; or at least an additional one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a possible thing to do, since you're not fetching a new page technically from the server, so the cookies won't be accessible.