# Can't read cookie 'a=a;path=/index' in route '/index'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

```js
// App.js
render() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={A} />
      <Route path="/index" component={B} />
    </Switch>
  )
}

// A.jsx
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie'

handleClick = () => {
  const cookies = new Cookies()
  cookies.set('a', 'a', { path: '/index' })
  this.props.history.push('/index')
}

render() {
  return <Component onClick={this.handleClick} />
}

// B.jsx
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie'

componentDidMount() {
  const cookies = new Cookies()
  console.log(cookies.get('a')) // undefined
}
```

When linking to route '/index' from route '/', I can't read the cookie 'a' in `componentDidMount`. Why is this happening? And how to access cookie 'a' in `B.jsx`?

Comment: Can you confirm that the `a` value is being saved in cookie from devtools?

Comment: @HemantMalik Yes. If I refresh the page, I can access the `a`.

Comment: if you can access `a`, then what's the problem?

Comment: @HemantMalik I have to refresh the page manually, otherwise I still can’t access `a` directly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to replicate the behaviour stated in OP and made some observation.

Here is what i found:
Consider we have a cookie having `path='/index'`.

1. When i set a cookie from any page with path as /index. That cookie is only accessible when i directly lands on /index page. Then i can access that path specific cookie on any path set via react.
2. if i land at any other page it shows cookie value as undefined.

The reason for this is react internally uses historyAPI for client side navigation and the cookie does not consider historyapi modified path as url and therefore doesn't serve cookie data.

A little explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010842/fetching-path-specific-cookie-on-pushstate)

So, in order to get the cookie data, you need to set `path='/'`, because it will allow cookie on all pages of website and thereby allow the cookie to be accessible anywhere on site resulting in getting cookie data irrespective of where the user has initially landed along with urls navigated using historyapi.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're setting cookie only for path `/index` and it mean that this cookie will be visible only for url called `/index`. You can even check column `Path` in chrome dev tool. Just set cookie to `/`.

Comment: and the B component has the `index` path and it should not be undefined inside it

Comment: Can you check cookies table in chrome dev tool?

Comment: @DarioFiore But...when click event is triggered, it is indeed called '/index', isn't it?  And `a` saved in cookie from devtools.